# LinkedIN - PHP Sample Code

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to implement the LinkeIN API with PECL oAuth Module, I have managed to import my contacts and the scrip works well on my Development envoirnment

But on my Live Server it raises an exception when I get redirected to my website after authentication(From Linked In Website)

I have confirmed the following:
1. The TimeZone is proper and My Server DateTime is set correct.
2. The CallBack URL is proper

Exception :
Exception caught! Response: 400 1302008612531 0 Unsupported POST target {/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,location,industry,distance,relation-to-viewer,current-status,current-status-timestamp,connections,summary,specialties,proposal-comments,honors,positions,educations,member-url-resources,picture-url,site-standard-profile-request,api-standard-profile-request)}
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'OAuthException' with message 'Invalid auth/bad request (got a 400, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)' in /var/www/html/contaxz/app/webroot/linkedIn/linkedin/Request.php:217 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/contaxz/app/webroot/linkedIn/linkedin/Request.php(217): OAuth->fetch('https://api.lin...') #1 /var/www/html/contaxz/app/webroot/linkedIn/example/index.php(23): LinkedIn_Request->pullConnections() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/contaxz/app/webroot/linkedIn/linkedin/Request.php on line 217

Please suggest

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: So the exact same script, without any changes to the end-point target, etc works fine on DEV server but not on LIVE server?  400 error is indicative of a bad entry (un-sported field selector, malformed request text, etc).  Can you make basic requests on the LIVE server?

Comment: Yes, That's correct exact same script works on DEV and its the sample script that I downloaded from LinkedIn website.

All I had to change are the following parameters:Application Key, Secret Key and the Return URL.

But it doesn't work on the LIVE server, which makes me believe it something to do with the server configuration.

Comment: Here is my OAuth Details on DEV
OAuth support enabled
PLAINTEXT support  not supported
RSA-SHA1 support  enabled
HMAC-SHA1 support  enabled
Request engine support  php_streams
source version  $Id:  

 OAuth Details on LIVE
OAuth support enabled
PLAINTEXT support  enabled
RSA-SHA1 support  enabled
HMAC-SHA1 support  enabled
Request engine support  php_streams, curl
source version  $Id: oauth.c 308061 2011-02-06 17:15:34Z jawed $
\nversion  1.0-dev

Comment: Well as you said, if all else are equal, is has to be a server issue.  on DEV, what versions of PHP, cURL, PECL OAuth are you using vs on LIVE?  Also, you've verified that the server timestamp is the same on both?

Comment: I have compared the site configuration on LIVE for PHP, Oauth, PECL, Curl - everything is similar to DEV 
I also have the timezone set to the correct values and only after setting the timezone and time it actully redirected me to LinkedIn website, Now I get this exception after I return from LinkedIn website and try to fetch the profile information
Note : The same script work on my DEV envoirnment, so I beleive it something to do with the server settings, please help?

Comment: It's got to be something with the server then, as you say.  You might want to try it on a third server to check the results.

Comment: Consider using the new Oauth2 authentication scheme instead of PECL Oauth1.x, i have always found it rather flaky depending on what build i was using, stuff would work or not at all. I made a lightweight PHP implementation based on the examples supplied by linkedin: https://github.com/EJTH/SLinkedIn/blob/master/examples/hello-world.php

Answer (score 0):

I had been breaking my head with the code, server configuration, oAuth installation, php and apache version, TimeZone and what not.... but had No Luck….

Finally, I found my way and thought of posting it here as it could help someone:

1. Stop Apache
2. Hunted for the PHP OAuth Module in the PHP lib directory in my case I found this at /usr/lib/php/modules/oauth.so
3. Copied PHP OAuth Module from my DEV server and uploaded it on LIVE server
4. Restarted apache and it worked!

Thanks
Ravi